# Reactively add or remove class

Tags: meteor

How can you reactively add or remove a class to an element with spacebars?
Also can anyone point me in the direction of the documentation for spacebars format.
Specifically logical functions in the {{#if condition1 && condition2}} style.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacebars currently don't provide a way to perform logical (nor other) functions for arguments.

If you need to make logical operations on your `if` helper arguments in several places, it is best to define your own custom helper:

```
UI.registerHelper('and', function(a, b) {
  return a && b;
});

{{#if and condition1 condition2}}
  ...
{{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no logical operations allowed in "if" statements, but you can workaround this by providing a custom helper. The easiest way to reactively modify your class would be:

```
<div class="{{#if isActive}}active{{/if}}"></div>
```

or just

```
<div class="{{yieldClass}}"></div>
```

where `yieldClass` is some (possibly reactive) helper in your template.